# Sql arithmetic overflow

Tags: sql, math, sql-insert

I have this query:

```
Insert into Course(name,age,id,facebookuser)
Values('Example',25,204813,blalbla@walla.com),
('Exmnumtwo',35,504813,email@walla.com)
```

Which gives me the error 8115: "arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int".

However, when I delete the ',' sign, everything works fine without any errors. What is causing the error?

Comment: `Insert into Course(name,age,id,facebookuser)
Values('Example',25,204813,'blalbla@walla.com'),
('Exmnumtwo',35,504813,'email@walla.com')`

Comment: @lad2025 I Do not see any differences between our codes . Help ?

Comment: you need to add quotes to the email addresses!

Comment: @Antonio Look more carefully

Comment: @spirographer My bad. i already have quotes in the Email address. this is not the problem.

Comment: make sure you placed the quotes correctly.  We can't help you with your question if you don't ask it properly.

Comment: @spirographer My bad. here is my code: (one second i will post it)

Comment: @spirographer http://sizmedia.com/my.php?i=tm3jjmurzzmx.png here is the code .. sorry for multi post i am new here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on the png you sent me http://up415.siz.co.il/up3/tm3jjmurzzmx.png

you need to make sure your IDs fit into the data size.  Your actual data would overflow 32 bit signed integers, so you need to make your id type 64 bits (or 32 bit unsigned) or choose IDs that have smaller numbers like your example above which fails because you didn't quote the email addresses.

Comment: I don't believe. I'm such a moron. it is was the error. how can i give the id variable an 64 bit ? (Sorry for bed English.)

Comment: try the bigint type when you define the schema.  please select my answer as the correct one when done :)

Comment: @spirographer i did it about your answer. i have another question if you can help me i will be glad. when i use where "something" = string i must to use where "something" like string , if i use = its give me an error. what the problem of using = instead of like?

Comment: @Antonio You must post this as a new question (or just search for the answer as there are many resources out there for this question).

Comment: @Nerdwood Only today i signed up here . it will take me few days to understand how everything works here. anyway , here is the code if you can help me - http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=kdnvtzommwvh.png

Comment: @Antonio it's probably a good idea to ask a separate question, and also to copy exactly the code that is breaking for you.  if = is causing an error for you and like is not, something strange is going on

Comment: @spirographer i took picture of the code - http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=kdnvtzommwvh.png , any better than that?  and i tried to open new question .. it says that i can open another one in 90 minutes.

Comment: @Antonio Each question in SO should only be about a single issue - that way the question(s) given answer the question. You will have to wait to ask a new question, unfortunately. But use the time to see if you can find someone else who has asked the question before.

Comment: @Nerdwood Ok i will search . you can't help me with my question ? :S

Comment: I think @Nerdwood is asking you to follow stackoverflow guidelines and to try to be resourceful in the meantime as well.

Comment: @spirographer Ok .. i think . i told you i'm new here
give me few days .

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `id` field of your `Course` table might be set to `smallint` which has a maximum value of 32,767.

Set the data type of the `id` field to `int` to increase the maximum value to 2,147,483,647.

List of integer data types in SQL Server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187745.aspx

Comment: Great! Glad that worked for you.  :)  Make sure you mark an answer as accepted if it fixed the problem.